# ColdFusion: Find out who digitally signed a PDF

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I am building a basic workflow in ColdFusion 2016 where the user has to collect signatures/approval for a project.

For various reasons, the user wants to be able to send out a PDF and collect back the digitally signed file for upload.

I am probably overthinking the process, but I am wanting to check the returned document against the internal record of who was *supposed* to be signing the document (it would also make it easier on the end-user since I can automatically mark the signature as received).

Using CFPDF I can validate that the document is signed and that the signature is valid, but I would like to be able to extract *who* signed it if possible (to test that the person who signed it was the person who was supposed to sign for it).

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

You have not shared any code so I have no idea what you have tried but according to the documentation ColdFusion 11 added support for reading signatures from PDF files.

[CFPDF Documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfpdf.html)

> Introduced in ColdFusion 11: Use the action ="sign", "unsign", "validatesignature", "readsignaturefields" for creating a digital signature, removing the digital signature, validating the signatures of a document, and for reading the signature fields respectively.

Further down at the bottom of the documentation:

> - For action ="readsignaturefields":
> - Reads all the signature fields and returns a query object in the variable indicated by attribute name. This query object will have five columns. The five columns are:
>
> a) Signed - fully qualified name of the signature field.
>
> b) Authored - indicates if this field can contain an author signature or not.
>
> c) Can_Be_Signed - whether this field can be signed.
>
> d) Can_Be_Authored - tells if this field is already signed or not
>
> e) Visible - tells if the field is visible.
>
> ```
> <!--- Read info about signature fields in a input pdf in a variable and dump it --->
> ```
>
> `<cfpdf action="readsignaturefields"
>          source="#filepath##inputfilename#" name="signinfo"
>          password="owner" />`
>
> `<cfdump var="#signinfo#"/>`